# generate scripts automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to generate automatic sql script of SP, views, triggers etc.

Is there any tool available that i can use where i just need to put in the name for example SP name and it generates a create script for that for me.

sql server 2005

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use T4 scripts as described here: [How to use T4 to generate CRUD stored procedures](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/01/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-crud-stored-procedures/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a tool. What functionality or ease-of-use did you need outside of SQL Management Studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell (free utility from MS) for this to script out any and all objects in a SQL Server database programmaticaly.

[Directions, including detailed script examples here.](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/using-powershell-to-generate-table-creation-scripts/)

[Download the newest version of PowerShell (v2) here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929)